# The enemy has three types of guns that shoot down a plane with probabilities of $0.1, 0.2$ and $0.3.$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations, conditional-probability

The enemy has three types of guns that shoot down a plane with probabilities of $0.1, 0.2$ and $0.3.$. 
It is known that the plane we sent turned out to be shot down.
It is also known that the enemy always uses exactly one gun with different frequencies 
`(for example, due to the difference in the prices of shells)`
the first with a frequency of $0.5$, the second $0.3$, the third $0.2$. 
What is the probability that this was the second gun?

Comment: I smell Bayes' theorem ... !

Comment: what problem in question makes people don vote !!!

Comment: @predactor, mostly the fact that you do not give context. It looks like a homework problem, you have not shown what you know, what you have tried, what about the problem you do not understand.

Comment: it is not homework  i am studying probabilities for machine learning and find this problem cant understand it

Comment: Have you tried using Bayes's theorem?

Comment: No , I thought it with conditional probability

Comment: The solution is 35%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thank for tell me that `Bayes' theorem`
I solved it like

- $p(A) = 0.1$
- $p(B) = 0.2$
- $p(C) = 0.3$
- $P(F|A) = 0.5$
- $P(F|B) = 0.3$
- $P(F|C) = 0.2$

using Bayes' theorem the result will be like that 
$\frac{0.2 * 0.3}{(0.2 * 0.3  + 0.5 * 0.1 + 0.2 * 0.3)} = 0.3529 = 3$5.29%$ $